# Symfony 3 : In can't inject service to my controller

Tags: php, dependency-injection, symfony

I created a custom helper class and declared it as service.
It works if I get this helper in my controller using :

```
$this->get('tee.helper.alert');
```

But I think is better with DI. Then I declared my controller as service too :

```
parameters:
    tee.helper.alert.class: TigreEtEuphrateBundle\Service\AlertHelper
    tee.controller.default.class: TigreEtEuphrateBundle\Controller\DefaultController

services:

#    CONTROLLERS
    tee.controller.default:
        class: "%tee.controller.default.class%"
        arguments: ["@tee.helper.alert"]

#    HELPERS
    tee.helper.alert:
        class: "%tee.helper.alert.class%"
        arguments: ["@session"]
```

But when my controller is called, I get a FatalError because the required argument in the constructor is not given.
This is basically my controller class :

```
class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    private $alert_helper;

    public function __construct(AlertHelper $alert_helper)
    {
        $this->alert_helper = $alert_helper;
    }
    // ...
}
```

What's wrong ? :/

Comment: Unrelated, but worth a mention I think. The Symfony Best Practices suggests to not use a variable for service class names. http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/business-logic.html#service-no-class-parameter Not the biggest thing, but still a readability improvement imho

Comment: Oh, thx for this feedback. I saw this practice in a framework based on Symfony. I didn't notice it was not the standard.

Comment: can you provide the specific error message?

Comment: The eror message is : "Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to MyBundle\Controller\DefaultController::__construct() must be an instance of MyBundle\Service\AlertHelper, none given"

Comment: is it MyBundle? - in definitions you have TigreEtEuphrateBundle

Comment: The problem is that you don't have the route setup to user the service.  Check the docs again or post your route.  You will probably need to add a call to setContainer as well.

Comment: Have you tried removing `extends Controller` ? Or clearing the cache ? Are you sure the file in which you defined those services is actually processed by the Bundle ?